# What is determined by S-Spec number on Intel CPUs?

Tags: cpu

What is determined by S-Spec(sample specification) number on Intel CPUs? For example I have an *i7-4790K* CPU with S-Spec number [SR219](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SR/SR219.html), but I have seen pictures of *i7-4790K* CPUs with S-Spec number [QG81](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/QG/QG81.html). What does this S-Spec number usually mean? Is it different from CPU stepping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What does this S-Spec number usually mean? Is it different from CPU stepping?

See the formal definitions later in this answer.

In this particular case, the difference is explained on the pages you linked to.

- The core stepping is the same for both S-Spec numbers.
- One of the S-Spec numbers is for a pre-production engineering sample chip.

> **Related S-Spec numbers**
>
> In addition to the SR219 S-Spec, this processor was also manufactured
> with one pre-production S-Spec number:
>
> [image]

Source [SR219 (Intel Core i7-4790K)](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/SR/SR219.html#related)

---

#### Definitions

- **Stepping** - This is basically the CPU's version number. Whenever Intel improves the manufacturing process, they make a new stepping. Steppings are typically two characters long (like C0, C1, or E0). It's also sometimes called the revision.
- **CPUID** (CPU IDentification) - This is an identification string (like 1067A) that allows software to find out what features your processor supports (stuff like SSE, MMX, VT-X, etc). All processors from the same stepping have the same CPUID.
- **sSpec** (specification number) - Unlike CPUID, each stepping of a processor has their own unique 4 or 5 character sSpec string (like SLBBM).

Source [How to get the CPUID, Stepping, or sSpec for an Intel CPU](http://www.delidded.com/how-to-get-the-cpuid-stepping-or-sspec-for-an-intel-cpu/)

---

#### How do I find out the S-Spec number of my CPU?

According to Intel physical inspection of the CPU is required:

> The sSpec number, also known as the specification number, is a five
> character string (SL36W or SR0PM for example) printed on the processor
> and processor label.
>
> How to find the sSpec number:
>
> - Read the boxed processor label as shown in Figure 1 below, or
> - Look at the markings on the processor as shown in Figure 2 below.
>
> Find the sSpec number on the boxed processor label (Figure 1):
>
> [image]
>
> Find the sSpec number in the processor markings (Figure 2 - two
> examples):
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Note:

- These sSpec number locations are subject to change. See your processor specification update documentation for the correct location for your specific processor.

Source [How to Find Your Processor Spec Number](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-016552.htm)

You can also use [Cpu-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) as follows:

> 1. Check the "Revision" field in CPU-Z and make a note of it.
> 2. Then search for your CPU here http://ark.intel.com/Default.aspx (use the search field on the top-right of the page).
> 3. Click on the matching result.
> 4. On the page you're given, click "ORDERING / SSPECS / STEPPINGS" over on the left side.
> 5. The view will change.
> 6. Look for your "Revision" (which is actually the "Stepping" or "Step"), and then you'll be able to find your CPU's sSpec in the "SPEC
>    Code" column.

Source [sSpec Number Finder](http://www.overclock.net/t/855668/sspec-number-finder)

Comment: I see, thanks! So each stepping seems to have its own S-Spec number? And while stepping information can be seen from OS(for example `grep -i step /proc/cpuinfo`), then S-Spec number can be seen only from physically inspecting the CPU?

Comment: Yes. According to intel physical inspection is required. Answer updated.