How come some Intel CPU models have the exact same stepping, but different s-Spec? And which s-Spec would be best in these cases?
Example:
SLAQJ
vs.
SLAZ3
Both seem to be virtually identical, even in core stepping. So why the different s-Specs? And which would be "better", objectively, if at all?

https://superuser.com/questions/1006389/what-is-determined-by-s-spec-number-on-intel-cpus seems plausible

Well, the answer's on one of the pages - one of them has a bug that causes a false positive overheating warning, the other dosen't.

This internal fault is fixed in the next S-Spec of the X9000, identified as SLAZ3.

I've no idea why or how you'd get a 'specific' nearly 2 decade old processor, or if that was even exposed to the average user - but its the same processor, one of which was patched. If you could check before purchase you obviously want the last S-Spec you can find
I suppose a modern processor would fix it with a microcode update - but it seems that there's other modern uses for a s-spec like differentiating stepping and engineering samples.

A great example of why two models would be identical would be the 13th-generation processors with the oxidation problem during manufacturing.  I have no idea if Intel would release a new model identical every day except to resolve or fix the manufacturing defect. The internal fault fixed by the two models seems like a nearly 1:1 comparison in 2024.
